# Git repo: ignore any sub-directories that have their own git repos

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore, ignore

- I want to track `*.md` files recursively under my main `~/Documents` dir.  And nothing else.
- However there's some subdirs under there that are their own projects with their own `.git` repos

  - So those dirs can be ignored entirely, I don't need to track their `*.md` files in my main `~/Documents/.git` repo
  - But I still want to leave those subdirs where they are

In my `~/Documents/.gitignore` file I have:

```
*
!*/
!*.md
```

When I try running `git add -A` ... it fails with an error on the first subdir it comes across that has its own `.git` repo:

```
error: 'some-subdir-project-that-can-be-ignored/' does not have a commit checked out
```

How can I get git to just skip any of those subdirs, without needing to specifically specify every one of them to be ignored by name (either now, or any others that appear in there later on).

Comment: The error `does not have a commit checked out` looks like the git submodule was never initialized. Do you just have subdirectories with their own .git directory and call them submodules (cause you tagged the question with git-submodules)? Because that's something else. See [git submodule documentation / tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule)

Comment: I just added the git-submodules tag here because while researching I saw that mentioned related to this error, so thought perhaps people who know about that subject might have some insights.  I have no intention of using them at any point (and have never used them in the past, don't really know much about them at all).  These subdirs that have their own git repos are all unrelated to each other.